# Generate 1 Letter in all Labels

Tags: vb.net

Good Morning

I am creating an application that has 100 `Labels` from `Label1` to `Label100`. My Target here is that all of that Labels must generate random letters in the alphabet no matter if it is repeated as long as its different.

Here is my code I tried.

```
  Dim validchars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
            Dim rand As New Random()

            For i As Integer = 1 To 1
                Dim idx As Integer = rand.Next(0, validchars.Length)
                Dim randomChar As Char = validchars(idx)
                sb.Append(randomChar)
            Next i
            Label1.Text = sb.ToString()
            Label2.Text = sb.ToString()
            Label3.Text = sb.ToString()
            Label4.Text = sb.ToString()
            Label5.Text = sb.ToString()
            Label6.Text = sb.ToString()
            Label7.Text = sb.ToString()
            Label8.Text = sb.ToString()
'and so on until i reached Label100
```

But my output is this :(

[image]

Please ignore the other letters because i tried to code until `Label50`

How can i achieve it? and is there other way to shorten up calling each label?

TYSM for future help

Comment: Are you wanting to generate the Labels with the random letter text in them? Or do they already exist? Also are you looking for C# or VB.NET assistance?

Comment: the letters already exist in there and i write it as a sample only. I want the letter text in them sir and as much as possible it is VB.Net

Comment: "no matter if it is repeated as long as its different" - that doesn't make sense. If it is repeated it can't be different.

Comment: later i will have 2 textbox and after that i will input a number from 1 to 100 and using that number i will display the generated number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the VB.NET version of the code provided by @mariocatch. I like it.

```
Dim alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Dim random As New Random()

For i As Integer = 0 To 99
    Dim label As New Label()
    label.Text = alphabet(random.Next(0, alphabet.Length)).ToString()

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label)
Next
```

This is the [Convertor](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx) used online for converting C# code to VB.NET code for reference.

Comment: @Andrew `FlowLayoutPanel` handles the positioning of added controls for you.

Comment: I need to stick with my code pattern because lately i will call the labels

Comment: later i will have 2 textbox and after that i will input a number from 1 to 100 and using that number i will display the generated number

Comment: I will used this code because it is the one that fits from what i need

Comment: You can remove the brackets around `[Next]`, they're superfluous. :)

Comment: Removed square brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're going for (c#)? Basically, creating the `Labels` on the fly, and adding them to a `FlowLayoutPanel` for stacking and positioning.

```
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = alphabet[random.Next(0, alphabet.Length)].ToString();

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Dim random As New Random()

For i As Integer = 0 To 99
    Dim label As New Label()
    label.Text = alphabet(random.[Next](0, alphabet.Length)).ToString()

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label)
Next
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer. See the VB.NET version below of the same code.

Comment: @Andrew FlowLayoutPanel handles the positioning of added controls for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1, with your existing form:**

I would have created the labels in the code and not in the designer, but if you already have them, you can do this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();
    var rnd = new Random();

    foreach (var label in labels)
    {
        label.Text = ((char)(rnd.Next(26) + 'A')).ToString();
    }
}
```

Simply loop through all the form's labels (you may filter them if necessary) and assign each one a random letter. And that's all. No need to use StringBuilders or an array with the letters.

I also used [Convertor](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx) to turn it into VB, I hope it works:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim labels = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    Dim rnd = New Random()

    For Each label As var In labels
        label.Text = CChar(rnd.[Next](26) + "A"C).ToString()
    Next
End Sub
```

**Option 2, starting from scratch:**

Finally, based on mariocatch's answer, which uses a `FlowLayoutPanel`, I suggest you do this:

1. Start with an empty form.
2. Add a `Panel`.
3. Set its `Dock` property to Bottom.
4. Add a `Button` inside.
5. Go to its `Anchor` property and deselect Top and Left (nothing selected).
6. Set the panel's height and center the button horizontally.
7. Add a `FlowLayoutPanel` in the middle of the form.
8. Set its `Dock` property to Fill.

And nothing else there. Then use this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim rnd = New Random()

    For i As Integer = 0 To 49
        Dim label = New Label()
        label.Width = 20
        label.Text = CChar(rnd.[Next](26) + "A"C).ToString()
        Me.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label)
    Next
End Sub
```

After this I think you can adjust all the details without any issue.

Comment: I need to stick with my code pattern because lately i will call the labels

Comment: later i will have 2 textbox and after that i will input a number from 1 to 100 and using that number i will display the generated number

Comment: What error? I tested the code before posting it. Have you moved to C#? This code should work perfectly with your current form. I don't understand the relation between all the labels and letters and this number you are saying.

Comment: @NyxAssasin, what error did you have? Did you try this option, which doesn't require to create an alphabet string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming labels up to 50 are the ones with the "F"s:

You've determined the value of sb once you left the loop. You're then taking that value and setting that to the text of each label, which is why it wouldn't work. You've also created a loop starting at 1 and ending at 1, which is a pretty pointless loop as it only runs once. If you modify the loop to generate 100 characters in the stringbuilder and then set the nth label to the nth character of the stringbuilder, this should work.

Comment: How can i code that sir? This is my first time doing this

Comment: Of course: the for loop by default increments by 1 until it reaches its final value. Since you've created a loop going from 1 to 1, it will only run once. Change that last value to 100 and it will generate that many characters in the stringbuilder. Once you've gotten the string, where you were previously doing ToString(), you do ToString()[n - 1]. This means that Label1.Text = sb.ToString()[0], and Label2.Text = sb.ToString()[1]

Comment: As an additional note, creating the labels in code would be the best way to go as many have already advised, however my explanation should work if you want to stick with how you've done it

Comment: I honestly think that using a `StringBuilder` when you don't need any string doesn't make sense. It's overcomplicating things.

Comment: Though it shouldn't have to need a string as the best method would to be to create the labels through code, in order to work with it not being that way a string would be necessary. This is because you would not be able to address each label in the loop and so would need a form of storage to hold the generated characters. I suppose an array of characters would do. I would also say that a string could be used without stringbuilder, however, as you could concatenate

Comment: It's more logical to simply loop through the labels and generate a random letter each time, like the other answers.

Comment: True, and this is what I meant by code created labels, however I focused this answer on working with what he already has for the labels, so he understands his mistake rather than replaces the whole code without learning what was wrong

Comment: later i will have 2 textbox and after that i will input a number from 1 to 100 and using that number i will display the generated number